# How do I include wildcard in url?

Tags: node.js, url

I have the below url to get user data

```
https://*****************/userdata(user_id='user_123')"
```

How do I make it configurable so that it returns data of users whose id start with user?
I tried

```
https://*****************/userdata(user_id LIKE 'user%')"
```

and it throws the following error
"org.odata4j.exceptions.BadRequestException: Illegal key (user_id LIKE 'user%')"
How do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You trying make HTTP GET request with URL `/userdata(user_id='user_123')"` or `/userdata(user_id LIKE 'user%')"`.

Firstly, you don't have a query, so to achieve this, use `?`, e.g. `/userdata?my_data=some_data`.

Secondly, if you want take user by id, please use REST or just pass a parameter like this:
`/userdata/:id`, so example URL: `/userdata/27`, where you have paramater id as 27.

Finally, if you have complex query, maybe it would better to use HTTP body to send data or even change API to GraphQL or else.

Comment: I added the filter as /userdata?$filter=startswith(userid,'user) eq true But the problem is from code it returns a 404 error whereas in reality the endpoint exists. Can you suggest on how to do it?

Comment: this should be local problem, hard to tell without scope